How do I count the number of unanswered (outstanding) emails on each day based on incoming day and duration?
I have a table of emails containing a start_time_dte (starting datetime) and a duration_total_seconds that represents the time from arrival of the mail to the answering of the mail.
For each day, I need to count the backlog of emails before 9 am. This is the number of mails that where sent before that time (so start_time_dte < 9 am of that day) and answered after 9 am of that day (so DATEADD(SECOND, duration_total_seconds, start_time_dte) > 9am that day). I will use end_date (DATEADD(SECOND, duration_total_seconds, start_time_dte)) in the example to make it easier to understand.
The issue is that emails can take multiple days to be answered and need to be counted in the backlog over multiple days. Every day that a mail has been sent before 9 am but not answered before than, it should be counted.
For example (format = dd/mm/yyyy):



start_time_dte
end_time_dte




01/04/2024 07:00:00
05/04/2024 08:00:00


02/04/2024 15:00:00
08/04/2024 12:00:00


02/04/2024 21:00:00
03/04/2024 07:00:00



So here the backlog table would look like:



Date
Backlog




01/04/2024
1


02/04/2024
1


03/04/2024
2


04/04/2024
2


05/04/2024
1


06/04/2024
1


07/04/2024
1


08/04/2024
1



I guess I would need some kind of group by using relative datetimes but I have not found anything that works yet.

What (R)DBMS are you using here? T-SQL is a dialect of SQL, used by several products. You mentioned SSMS in your question as well (though as noise, so removed), however, that's just an IDE (like) application, so doesn't help narrow down what it is you're using. Are you perhaps using SQL Server? Azure Synapse? Sybase?

As for the problem, do you ave a calendar table? If not, you should invest in the time to make one; it'll make this far easier.

This is (some what) simple if you have a calendar table; if you don't then create one (I'm not covering that here, as there's a wealth of resources on how to achieve this).
The need to treat the day start as 09:00 makes it a little "awkward", but you can get around that by using a CTE to subtract 9 hours from the time, making 09:00 the "start" of the day instead. Then you can simply check if Calendar date is greater than the start time, and less than end time.
This gives you the following:
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -9, start_time_dte) AS start_time_dte,
           DATEADD(HOUR, -9, end_time_dte) AS end_time_dte
    FROM (VALUES (TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'01/04/2024 07:00:00',103),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'05/04/2024 08:00:00',103)), --Please don't use ambigious date literals
                 (TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'02/04/2024 15:00:00',103),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'08/04/2024 12:00:00',103)), --Please don't use ambigious date literals
                 (TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'02/04/2024 21:00:00',103),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),'03/04/2024 07:00:00',103))
         )V(start_time_dte,end_time_dte))
SELECT C.CalendarDate,
       COUNT(*) AS Backlog
FROM tbl.Calendar C --Your calendar table
     JOIN CTE ON C.CalendarDate >= CTE.start_time_dte AND C.CalendarDate < CTE.end_time_dte
WHERE C.CalendarDate >= '20240401'
  AND C.CalendarDate <= '20240408'
GROUP BY C.CalendarDate;

